# Trying to EXEC a stored procedure on another server

Tags: sql-server

I created a stored procedure in a database called `DBA_Test`. I went to another server and tried to execute this stored procedure using

```
EXEC *LinkedServerName*.DBA_Test.dbo.spLoad_Clients_Monthly_Filings
```

When I try to execute the query, I get the following error:

> Server '*LinkedServerName*' is not configured for RPC.

When the line is in the query window of SSMS, the `DBA_Test` is underlined in red and hovering over it shows a message:

[image: Query_Window]

> Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'DBA_Test'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

I have everything spelled correctly and the stored procedure is listed in the database as seen here:

[image: DBA_Test_Stored_Procs]

I tried executing the stored procedure on the same server, but from another database, and it ran fine. Every other server I switched to gave the red line error saying that the database could not be found in `sysdatabases`. I have all the linked servers working correctly.

Comment: After adding the linked server, you have to add login mappings and use a login which is mapped to the linked server to a login with appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create linked server you need to set RPC (and maybe RPC out):

[image: New linked server]

Regarding your second question, sometimes SSMS doesn't correctly parse linked server objects

Comment: That seems to work now.  Thank you for the quick response.